# Jmeter is not recording any script of any site and gives JAVA connection error

Tags: jmeter

I want to do performance test of my website with the help of Jmeter. i have installed Jmeter version 3.3 and did all the set up with reference of below website. I have done all proxy setting of Jmeter and in browser.

[Pdf step by step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdfhttps://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)

But while recording the script, browser does not allow to run the website on Jmeter proxy and gives *"java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out"* error.

Please guide.

Answer (score 0):

You most probably didn’t configure the enterprise proxy on JMeter:

- http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#proxy_server